# Generalization of finding $L_\infty$ centroid in $R^2$ via rotating and minimizing sum of $L_1$ distances

Tags: algorithms, reference-request

Given a set of points $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^2$, suppose one wants to find:

$\text{argmin}_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \lVert x_i - x_j\rVert_\infty$

i.e. the point which minimizes the sum of the $L_\infty$ distances to the other points.

One can apply the matrix $R =\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ to get a new set of points $Rx_1, \dots, Rx_n$, instead minimize:

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \lVert Rx_i - Rx_j \rVert_1 = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \lVert R(x_i - x_j)\rVert_1 = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \lVert x_i - x_j\rVert_\infty $

Minimizing the sum of $L_1$ distances is pretty easy, while the sum of maxes seems harder.

This was a bit surprising to me. At first I thought it might be because the $L_1$, and $L_\infty$ norms are dual to each other, but in $R^n$ for $n > 2$, the $L_\infty$ norm isn't just a rotation and scaling of the $L_1$ norm.

Is there a way to generalize this into higher dimensions? I'd also be interested in a reference for this method so I could see some discussion of why this property is true in R^2 but not in higher dimensions.

Comment: This is based on the identity $\max(|a|,|b|)=\frac{|a+b|}{3}+\frac{|a-b|}{2}$. But for a maximum of a larger number of numbers the formulas get a [lot uglier](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13253).

Comment: Geometrically you can see that there is such a linear transformation because the balls in those norms have the same shape. They are both squares. However, for larger dimension the balls of $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{\infty}$ are hypercubes, while the balls of $\left\|\cdot\right\|_1$ are ... I don't know if to give them a name ... a tetrahedron for dimension $3$  and iterated suspensions of the tetrahedron in higher dimensions, not hypercubes. So, any such transformation would have to be non-linear.

Comment: @plop I guess the link implies that there's some non-linear transformation one could replace R with in R^3 at least. It's not clear how the complexity would scale with dimension though.

Comment: In $L_\infty$ and $L_1$ balls are convex. So, count vertices and you will get why it is forced to be more and more complicated. In dimension $3$ the balls of $L_\infty$ have $8$ vertices, while the balls of $L_1$ has $6$. As you increase dimension the number of vertices of balls in $L_\infty$ gets multiplied by $2$ each time, while the number of vertices of the ball of $L_1$ gets increased by $2$.